# How to use CustomUser model and OpenID together in Django for authentication?

Tags: python, django, django-models, openid

I'm learning Python Django framework. Thanks to StackOverFlow Community, i have learned how to use open-id in django (social_auth i'm using ).

with social_auth, sign in and sign out process are pretty easy and practical. But i want  to build friendship relationship between users, for this  i created  new model class which is extended from `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`  and  add control when new user is created in auth_table, i create new user on CustomUser Table.(It is not efficient  because the parameters coming from open-id are different for each open-id connection)
My model code is here

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.models import UserManager
# Create your models here.


class CustomUser(User):
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    web_pages = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField("self")
```

And How can i use CustomUser model and OpenID together in Django for authentication?

Any Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to extend the User class in Django is to provide user profile class. See [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users). You can then just use the User model as always and get the profile instance on demand.